# how to merge two columns with prioritization R

Tags: r

I have a data frame which looks like that :

| MANUAL.ID | AUTO.ID |
| --- | --- |
| Barbar | Barbar |
|  | Barbar |
| Barbar | Pippip |
| Pippip,Hypsav | Barbar |
| Pippip | Barbar |
| Barbar,Pippip |  |

Basically I whould merge the both columns in a single called species and obtain this kind of result and we always prioritize the manual.id column  :

| species |
| --- |
| Barbar |
| Barbar |
| Barbar |
| Pippip,Hypsav |
| Pippip |
| Barbar,Pippip |

What can I do to get the result ?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `coalesce` function from `dplyr` if your values are NA like this:

```r
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  mutate(species = coalesce(MANUAL.ID, AUTO.ID)) %>%
  select(species)
#>         species
#> 1        Barbar
#> 2        Barbar
#> 3        Barbar
#> 4 Pippip,Hypsav
#> 5        Pippip
#> 6 Barbar,Pippip
```

---

If your cells are empty strings you could first replace them to NA with `na_if` like this:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>%
  mutate(across(everything(), ~ na_if(.x, ""))) %>%
  mutate(species = coalesce(MANUAL.ID, AUTO.ID)) %>%
  select(species)
#>         species
#> 1        Barbar
#> 2        Barbar
#> 3        Barbar
#> 4 Pippip,Hypsav
#> 5        Pippip
#> 6 Barbar,Pippip
```

<sup>Created on 2023-04-19 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: it doesn't works. I have the error : Error in `mutate()`:
ℹ In argument: `across(everything(), ~na_if(.x, ""))`.
Caused by error in `across()`:
! Can't compute column `lat`.
Caused by error in `na_if()`:
! Can't convert `y` <character> to match type of `x` <double>.                                                    I tried to replace the na_if(.x, "") by na_if(.x, "") or na_if(.x, "0") but it doesn't work anymore...

Comment: hI @lobarth, you have to make sure your columns have the right type. So maybe it should be numeric or character instead.

Comment: and do you know a way to charge the type of column ? In character for example ?

Comment: You could use `as.character` or `as.numeric` for example.

Comment: but I just checked by using class() and the both columns are of class character

Comment: Aah I see, you don't need the first `mutate` function when your data already has `NA` values. I just did that to make sure your values are NA.

Comment: No its not that. I try to remove the first mutate and it works but my empty value are not NA so the result hide the correct value on auti.id colum and replace it by the empty value

Comment: I need to replace empty values by NA first and then merge the column